# jQuery: Find element outside of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the first element that matches my criteria OUTSIDE of my container.
  I know how to find it if it's inside but when it's outside, I"m not sure. 
 I want to only select the **very first element** it finds also, this is my attempt:

```js
   $('.text').click(
    function(){
        $(this).css('font-size', '50px');
        $(this).next('span').css('color','red');

        });
```

```css
.one{
  background:orange;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
```

So, in my example.  If you click on the first text in the orange box labeled "text", it will change the color of the span directly outside it to red.  Above the box and below it.  It will not affect the other span, just the very first one.

Comment: Did my answer solve the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35263259/4763793

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$(this).parent().next('span:first').css('color','red');
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/5/)

[.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) :Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

[:first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) : Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set.

Answer (score 0):

This will find very first elements above and below clicked div

```
$(this).parent().next('span:first').css('color','red');
$(this).parent().prev('span:first').css('color','red');
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/yj0vby60/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.text').click(
    function(){
        $(this).css('font-size', '50px');
        $(this).parent().next('span:first').css('color','red');

        });
```

```css
.one{
  background:orange;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
span{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
  text
  </p>
 
</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.parent()` which will return parent element of mentioned element. `.next()` will return next element of the current element. `:first` will return first element from matched elements.

Try this:

```js
$('.text').click(
  function() {
    $(this).css('font-size', '50px');
    $(this).parent('.one').next('span:first').css('color', 'red');

  });
```

```css
.one {
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
    text
  </p>

</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
    text
  </p>

</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
<div class="one">

  <p class="text">
    text
  </p>

</div>
<span>First</span>
<span>Second</span>
```